# Vector Length in MapInfo

Tags: vector, size, mapinfo

Does anyone know how to calculate the exact length of a vector in MapInfo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use

```
Dim vector_length As Float
vector_length = ObjectLen(Obj, "m")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefere to use CartesianObjectLen instead of ObjectLen

[CartesianObjectLen vs ObjectLen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjyS1.png)

```
dim o as object
select * from TABLE where Unique Column = Unique Code into sel
o=sel.obj
print(CartesianObjectLen(o, "m"))
```